# Reference to a figure

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

When referring to a figure, the output in my pdf is not a number, but 'Figure xx'. For example: if I use the phrase

*This is figure \ref{test}.*

the output in my pdf file is always:

*This is figure Figure 1.3.*

I would like to know why LaTeX shows the prefix 'Figure' and not simply the number of the figure. Here is the general code that I use for a figure:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{Test.eps}
    \caption{Test}
    \label{test}
\end{figure}
```

Interestingly, when referring to a subfigure, this issue does not occur; it only occurs when I want to refer to a 'whole' figure. As my document is quite extend (thesis), I use a lot of packages in my preamble, but even after an extensive quest I could not figure out what the problem might be.

My preamble:

```
\usepackage{a4wide}                         
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}                   
\usepackage[small,bf,hang]{caption}     
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                           
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                   
\usepackage{titlesec}                   
\usepackage{subfig}                     
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite} 
\usepackage{chngcntr}                   
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}    
\usepackage{fixltx2e}                   
\usepackage{wrapfig}                    
\usepackage{arevtext,arevmath}          
\usepackage{enumitem}                   
\usepackage[Gray,squaren,thinqspace,thinspace]{SIunits} 

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}              
\usepackage{chemscheme}
\usepackage{epstopdf}                   
\usepackage[varioref=true,journal=jcp]{chemstyle}  
\usepackage{float}
```

% ************ General lay out ************

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}             
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}    
\pagenumbering{arabic}                  
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
```

% ************ Font in titles and text ************

```
\usepackage[scaled=.95]{helvet}         
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

% ************ Fancy chapter titles ************

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\sffamily\huge\raggedleft}    
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}
    \rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.4cm}{\thechapter} \rule{5cm}{1.45cm}}} 
  {10pt}{\Huge}  % Chaptertitelgrootte
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{2pt}{90pt}
```

% ************ Fancy captions for images ************

```
\captionsetup{
margin=1ex,
font={small, sf},
labelfont={bf, sf},
labelsep= endash}
```

% ************************

```
\makeatletter 
\def\@seccntformat#1{\llap{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
```

Comment: Please add your preamble here because \ref should print just the number. Do you use the cleveref package?

Comment: I have added my preamble now.

Comment: With `cleveref`, typing: _This is \cref{test}_ will result in: _This is figure 1.3_, and _\Cref{test} shows that…_ in: _Figure 1.3 shows that…_ It cooperates with `varioref`.

Answer (score 9):

This is caused by `chemstyle` package, and to be more precisely by the `varioref` option. Set it to false if you don't need it.